# gcloud python: how to construct query with OR condition

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

It seems there is no way to construct query with OR condition. Has anyone hit this issue or know when this will be done or any workaround.

What I want to achive something like this with OR:

```
query = datastore.query(kind='Article',
                         filters=[('url', '=', 'url1'),
                                  ('url', '=', 'url2')]
                       )
```

But this filter works as AND not OR.

Answer (score 3):

`OR` is not a supported query construct in Google Cloud Datastore.

The current way to achieve this is to construct multiple queries  client-side and combine the result sets.

For reference, you should read through the [Datastore Queries](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/queries) documentation:

> The Datastore currently only supports combining filters with the AND operator. However it's relatively straightforward to create your own OR query by issuing multiple queries and combining the results:

Answer (score 1):

Python runtime supports ["IN" query filter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries?hl=en#Python_Property_filters).

Note, however, that this is just a convenience: under the hood, "IN" query is translated into a series of independent queries each looking for one value on the list.

Comment: I don't see 'IN' in gcloud python library. Can you point me in gcloud doc if it does exist in there.

Comment: Sorry, I was not probably clear enough, I'm trying to use gcloud python library which is different than general python datastore implementation. https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/datastore-entities.html

Comment: I would say the reason `AND` is supported but `OR` isn't is that *most* Datastore queries are index scans so an `AND` query is a scan of a *custom* index, whereas an `OR` query can be achieved by multiple queries (scans) of a simple index.  As @AndreiVolgin says, `IN` is syntactic sugar.